# Tracking users "most clicked"

Tags: tracking

I'm looking for a way to track (hopefully non-logged in) users most viewed items. I found a few helpful addons, but the closest I could get is determining that users most recent views, or how many times they viewed a certain page via cookie. I'd like to eventually be able to take the "most viewed" information and put a few if statements to order the content shown to put the stuff they view the most up top. Does anyone have any experience in something like this? Or if someone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Great idea, however I have one question: you say you want to track users' most viewed items. Do you actually mean that you want to track their most viewed channel entries or do you want to track page views?

Comment: I wanted to check (most viewed) channel entry views to be more specific, and as Anna pointed out down below, there is a really nice way to do it built into expression engine! The next step I'm trying to take is to break down the views by category, although I'm not sure that method will provide a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can track visits to your single entry pages with the [**Entry “Views” Tracking Tag**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_tracking.html).

> ExpressionEngine lets you track how many times a channel entry has
>   been “viewed” on a particular page. Up to four different instances of
>   the view counter can be used (each on a different page), enabling you
>   to track different aspects of an entry independently. For example you
>   can use view counter “one” to track views on your comments page and
>   view counter “two” to track views on your permalink page.
>
> **Note**
>   The view tracking counter works in conjunction with the
>   {exp:channel:entries} tag. Although you can show the number of views
>   in any instance of your channel entries tag, the counter will only
>   increment on pages that show a single-entry pages. Single entry pages
>   are ones that show only a single entry, specified dynamically by the
>   ID number or URL Title in the URL, such as comment or permalink pages.

You can then [**orderby the view count**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby) or write conditionals against the count in your channel:entries tag.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This worked great. Would it be at all possible to do this with categories? Or perhaps something that was associated with certain entries (similar to a category). To be more specific, I was I wanted to show the more-clicked-on categories first (maybe 1-2 entry out of each) as apposed to the single entries. I tried a few different ways, but couldn't seem to find a good way to associate the view on the single entry to it's category. Thanks again!!

Comment: You're welcome. This only works for tracking hits to single entry pages.